# Loading dynamic .ini identifiers

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I am creating a virtual version of my student planner which basically lets you make notes what homework you have for what subject.

Here is the interface:
[image]

The user selects the subject from the combobox and types in some notes in the adjacent memo. When they are done they will click the 'Save' button which will save it into an .ini file. The selected date will become the section name, the subjects will become the identifier and the text in the memo will become the values for each identifier.

**Note:** There are 7 possible subjects.

My problem is loading the combo boxes and the memos when the date is selected seeing as the identifiers are always different for each date.

**For example:**

On the 16th of February the user input (interface):

English - Read up to page 127 of novel.
Maths - Complete chapter 6.

For the 16th of February it will look like this in the .ini file:

> [16/02/12]
>   English=Read up to page 127 of novel.
>   Maths=Complete chapter 6.

On the 20th of February the user inputs (interface):

SOSE - Read textbook.
Legal Studies - Fill in online survey.

For the 20th of February it will look like this in the .ini file:

> [20/02/12]
>   SOSE=Read textbook.
>   Legal Studies=Fill in online survey.

Now you see if a user selects 16th of February to view what their tasks are, it wouldn't be possible to load because each identifier varies.

Is there a better alternative to the .ini file? How can I go about achieving this?

Comment: you should consider using a lightweight database like http://www.sqlite.org/ as the project grows, the complexity will grow with it and it will make it harder to maintain, just my two cents.

Comment: User0815 mentioned the same thing, but thank you for you suggestion. Although I plan to have the ini files erased periodically though. What do you think about this?

Comment: ahhh, sorry, I haven't read all the comments. a database would be much more easier to maintain than ini files, for example relationships between dates and disciplines and maybe students(?) Erasing is not a good idea(IMHO) you should keep a history for statistics or just to be there, it won't eat that much storage space, I'm sure you can come up with usage scenarios for history, i.e. if every Wednesday there's homework for Math, but at different time, the application can ask on Tuesday the student something like "Hey, got homework for Math today?"

Comment: I thought storing all this data would eat a lot of storage space which is why I mentioned that I intended to, periodically, erase the data, but I understand. I think I'll change over to the embedded database right now. The only problem I have right now is working with databases.

Comment: then don't change anything just yet, learn a bit about databases, and as soon as you get used to it, modify the application, implement an import mechanism which will import data from *.ini to db and you will love it. By the way, storage is pretty cheap today and based on what I see, your app will need around 12 months to reach at most 200MB storage usage...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `TIniFile.ReadSections` to get the individual dates, and `TIniFile.ReadSection` to get the individual items within that section. Here's a quick example:

```
// Sample ini file

[16/02/12]
English=Read up to page 127 of novel.
Maths=Complete chapter 6. 

[20/02/12]
SOSE=Read textbook.
Legal Studies=Fill in online survey.
```

Code:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, IniFiles;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    ListBox1: TListBox;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    procedure ListBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FIni: TMemIniFile;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

const
  IniName = 'd:\Temp\SampleNotes.ini';

procedure TForm2.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  FIni.Free;
end;

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FIni := TMemIniFile.Create(IniName);
  Memo1.Lines.Clear;
  FIni.ReadSections(ListBox1.Items);
end;

procedure TForm2.ListBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Section: string;
begin
  if ListBox1.ItemIndex > -1 then
  begin
    Section := ListBox1.Items[ListBox1.ItemIndex];
    FIni.ReadSection(Section, Memo1.Lines);
  end;
end;

end.
```

The above produces this:

[image: Sample output image] [image: Sample output image 2]

Comment: Thank you for writing that piece of code up Ken. I will find a way to adopt it to my code. I've noticed you've used TMemIniFile instead of TIniFile. What are the advantages over TIniFile does TMemIniFile have?

Comment: `TIniFile` uses the WinAPI's `ReadPrivateProfileString/WritePrivateProfileString` functions, which have some issues with caching, and sometimes will lose changes. `TMemIniFile` has the same methods, but a totally different implementation, and has an `UpdateFile` method that ensures the data gets saved. If you remember to call it when you're finished updating the file, it's much more likely your changes will actually be saved. `TIniFile` also has issues sometimes with saving to network paths, which `TMemIniFile` doesn't. They're almost 100% compatible and in the same unit.

Answer (score 8):

There is no problem with using a `TIniFile` for this. The class has a method [`ReadSections()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/IniFiles.TIniFile.ReadSections) which you can use to read all days with homework, and a method [`ReadSection()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/IniFiles.TIniFile.ReadSection) to read all entries for a given day.
You could also use [`ReadSectionValues()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/IniFiles.TIniFile.ReadSectionValues) to read complete lines (subject and task) which you would then need to split at the first = char.

Comment: I would use `ReadSection()` instead to determine the available keys (subjects), then `ReadString()` the individual values (notes) as needed. Since you need to know what subjects are present, `ReadSection()` makes that list easier to obtain than parsing the result of `ReadSectionValues()`.

Comment: @petersmileyface ...in addition to mghie: think about useable memorysize and speed of this solution when our "database" grow up. Maybee time for an embedded database.

Comment: @petersmileyface: There are more reasons to choose a database over an INI file. Imagine someone changes their date format between invocations of your program. Imagine the memo containing multiple lines of text, with equal signs and square brackets in them. A database with properly typed fields is just a better solution, even if you have only one user and the number of entries is small.