# How to correctly add sections of the .ini file to ComboBox

Tags: delphi, ini

How to correctly add sections of the .ini file to ComboBox, depending on the selection in the ComboBox key values ​​displayed in Label and shellExecute to open the selected web page

My .ini file

```
[Google]
Adress=https://www.google.co.uk
Description=Example description1
[Ask]
Adress=http://www.ask.com
Description=Example description2
[Bing]
Adress=https://www.bing.com
Description=Example description3
```

My Code:

```
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  INI: TIniFile;
implementation

procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  INI := TIniFile.Create(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'setup.ini');
  try
    INI.ReadSections(ComboBox1.Items);
  finally
    INI.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
  var
  AdressIni:string;
  begin
  AdressIni := INI.ReadString(ComboBox1.Items[ComboBox1.ItemIndex],'Adress', '');
  Label1.Caption := INI.ReadString(ComboBox1.Items[ComboBox1.ItemIndex],'Description', '');
  ShellExecute(handle, 'open', 'AdressIni', nil, nil, sw_shownormal);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: So you are trying to populate a combobox with the data taken from an ini?

Comment: Yes. And continue to use the key value,Like in the code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9338283/62576 will show you how to do the combobox/inifile parts.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing wrong parameters to `ShellExecute` procedure. You are passing `AdressIni` as string passed as first parameter (URL) instead of passing reference to your `AdressIni` variable.

Here is how you can do it:

```
procedure TForm3.ComboBox1Select(Sender: TObject);
var AdressIni: string;
begin
  Ini := TIniFile.Create('D:\Proba.ini');
  try
    //Form3.Caption := INI.ReadString(ComboBox1.Items[ComboBox1.ItemIndex],'Adress', '');
    AdressIni := INI.ReadString(ComboBox1.Text,'Adress','');
    Form3.Caption := AdressIni;
    ShellExecute(handle, 'open', PCHAR(AdressIni), nil, nil, sw_shownormal);
  finally
    INI.Free;
  end
end;
```

Notice that I'm reading `ComboBox1.Text` instead of `ComboBox1.Items[ComboBox1.ItemIndex]` since `ComboBox1.Text` contains text of currently selected Item.

Comment: How do you mean it doesn't work? I have tested this on my computer prior posting and it worked fine

Comment: How does this work? if you have not added a .ini file to your ComboBox? When I added, instead of the WWW page, the project window opens. And Label does not display anything

Comment: You still populate your ComboBox the way you used to do with your own code. Also make sure you are using correct path to your INI file (I used different one in my code). Because if you are not the `INI.ReadString` will be returning empty (default) strings